# Alternative for nth-child(3n+1) without javascript for IE versions below 9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-selectors

I have a requirement where I am making margin-left:0 for 1st, 4th, 7th and so on div elements.
I have used this code:

```
div:nth-child(3n+1) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
```

But this is not working in IE versions below 9. Although I am able to fix it using javascript but I need some solution using css. I would be very thankful for the help.

Comment: Why does it *have* to be CSS?

Comment: use css to fix something that IE's css engine doesn't support? that'd be like trying to use your unstartable car to go for a drive...

Comment: Because I want my application to work without javascript

Comment: Have you met ie7-js?  http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot emulate a complex `:nth-child()` formula using a CSS selector unless you repeat hardcoded selectors for each and every element individually, which will be a waste of time anyway so you may as well use JavaScript instead (e.g. to add a class to those elements then select by that class).

Comment: Ya thats what I was also searching I didnt get anything or rather I can provide a specific classname to those classes and apply the required css.

Answer (score 0):

Without using javascript the easiest way would be to add a class to the relevant divs with your desired CSS.

HTML

```
<div class='my_class'>Hello World</div>
```

CSS

```
.`my_class{margin-left: 0;}`
```

Comment: can you please elaborate further and make it easy for the viewers?